Blender animation changes when exporting as gltf
book.blend is the blender animation I created based on this tutorial. When I export this as GLTF, it becomes very different (no bending of the pages, spines scale and move differently).
How can I export this animation correctly? I plan to use this in ThreeJS.
I tried "baking" animations and applying modifiers, but they didn't work.

it's probably because it's not possible to export Blender's constraints which are used in the tutorial. So any part of the animation which relies on constraints won't work outside of Blender.
